# Route traffic to different IP addresses while using a single outgoing IP

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, routing

So I have 3 servers, each with his own public IP address. Now I also have a virtual IP(178.x.x.x) that's publicly accessible and it's mounted to one of those servers.
The virtual IP can be moved between servers at anytime.

It's possible to somehow route traffic(iptables or any other tool) to use that virtual IP, so users have to create firewall rules only for it?

The connection could also be two ways, for example if "Service 1" tries to connect to an external service.

[image]

As a note each server has Ubuntu 20.04 installed and a two network interfaces(one for the public ips, including the virtual one, and one for a private IP that can be accessed only between servers)

I thought about it for couple of days now and I just need some advices, thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're implementing a Load Balancer. There's software out there that already does this and even manages the transfer of TCP (session) based connections between servers if the primary one crashes or otherwise becomes unavailable.

Comment: The ROUTING is implemented by the ROUTER and we don't know anything about that - so your question is unanswerable.